# Использования своего кода в чужом проекте

Tags: веб-программирование, юридические-аспекты

У меня есть не понятный для меня вопрос, помогите разобраться.

Допустим я работал в компании и разрабатывал систему, работал не официально, ничего не подписывал, могу ли я использовать код из этого проекта для написания такой же системы уже в другом проекте и компании, первая компания может что-либо предъявить?

Comment: Почему не можете? Вы же не подписывали никаких документов... Например у себя на работе я подписывал такие документы.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, если не подписано NDA - то ничего не будет

Comment: В том невероятном случае, если первая компания захочет судебных разбирательств - вы будете доказывать, что код написан вами, а компания будет доказывать, что код вы украли у нее. Кто кого перебодает.

Comment: Если ты не подписывал никаких соглашений о конфиденциальности и правах собственности, то вполне можешь использовать свой код в любом проекте.

Comment: Не уверен насчёт РФ, в рб достаточно наличия трудового договора для того, чтобы код признавался "служебным произведением". Если у вас ни договора, ни других бумаг не было - код полностью ваш.

Comment: Вроде как во многих странах СНГ код является интеллектуальной собственностью создателя кода (т.е. юридически ваш код - ваша собственность) пока вы не подписали договор передачи авторских прав. В вашем случае беспокоиться повода нет, в любом случае доказать что вы каким-то образом украли этот код никто не сможет - это очень дорогостоящие и не точные экспертизы. Так что пользуйте на здоровье.